# Is there a way to tell eslint to block console but not console.error?

Tags: node.js, eslint

I want to use the rule [no-console](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console.html) but I also want to log errors in my application.

Is there a way to ignore calls to `console.error` or ir there another way to log it on stderr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always write to [`process.stderr`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stderr). But if you want to know if you really can write to the standard output streams, you need to check if Node.js is started in TTY mode, as shown in [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the no-console rule with the following options:

`{ "allow": ["warn", "error"] }`